# WinAPI WaitForMultipleObjects -- block on an Event and a third-party function?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

Windows 7 x64 and MS Visual Studio Express 2013, WinApi, C.

Is it possible to use `WaitForMultipleObjects` to wait for either an Event from another thread, *OR* for a third-party library function to return?

I have a thread which goes in a loop.  Pseudo code like this:

```
while(1) {
    result1 = poll_for_third_party_bool(...); // return immediately
    if (result1) {do some stuff}

    result2 = WaitForMultipleObjects(list_of_events, 0); // return immediately
    switch(result2) {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0: bla bla
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0+1: bla bla
    }
}
```

Specifically, the third party library is currently polling for a GPIO on a USB SPI adapter (Aardvark), but the library also supports a function which blocks until the GPIO changes.  I'd like to block on that function OR wait until some other event happens, all in a single WaitFor... .  Otherwise I'm spinning in a loop which is annoying.

I'd like to write:

```
list_of_events = {some_function_ptr, event1, event2};
while(1) {
    result = StartFunctionAndWaitForMultipleObjects(list_of_events, 0); // start some_function but return immediately.
    switch(result) {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0: do_stuff_when_some_function_returns;
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0+1: bla bla1
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0+2: bla bla2
    }
}
```

One problem is the library functions only work from the same thread that opened the adapter, so the whole thing needs to be in the same thread loop, ie waiting for input GPIOs, or responding to request events to send SPI data from another thread.  I don't think I can start a third thread just to block on the GPIO input.

Thanks

Comment: 'I don't think I can start a third thread just to block on the GPIO input' - try it.  If the lib. was not thread-safe, why would it provide blocking calls?.

Comment: did you consider using win32 thread pool? do you have to support WIndows XP?